# What is the difference between horloge and pendule?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

What's the difference between *horloge* and *pendule*? All I know so far is what is given on Collins English-French dictionary: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/clock.

Answer (score 5):

The most common word for “clock” is *horloge* (***une horloge***). Any device whose purpose is to tell the time can be called an *horloge*, except for small ones that fit in a pocket or are worn around the wrist: those are called “watches” in English and *montres* in French (***une montre***). An alarm clock is ***un réveil***; you'd only refer to it as *horloge* if you were using it to display the time and you weren't using its alarm functionality.

The word *horloge* is also used for a part of a device that tells the time, for example for the clock on a video recorder or a kitchen appliance, or a clock application on a computer. A device whose purpose is to keep the time (but not directly display it) is also called *une horloge*, for example *une horloge atomique* (an atomic clock), or the clock of a circuit in electronics.

***Une pendule*** is a particular type of clock that uses a pendulum (a [pendulum clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_clock)). A pendulum is *un pendule* (masculine), a pendulum clock is *une pendule* (feminine), originally short for “*une horloge à pendule*”. More rarely, the word *pendule* can be used for any kind of *horloge* in the sense of a device whose sole purpose is to tell the time. You can use *pendule* for an electric clock, but not for the time display on an appliance.

The characterisation of *horloge* as “large” and *pendule* as “small” in the Collins dictionary makes no sense at all. If anything, a *pendule* would tend to be bigger; the less a clock looks like a pendulum clock, the less likely people are to call it *pendule*.

Answer (score 1):

Both display the time.

A *pendule* (feminine) is an increasingly rare kind of *horloge* which works thanks to a *pendule* (pendulum: masculine).

On the other hand, *horloges* can use anything like springs or electricity to operate.

Answer (score 1):

Techniquement, une pendule est une catégorie d'horloge qui fonctionne à l'aide d'un pendule, ou balancier, un objet qui pend et qui oscille.

[image]

([crédit: "By Ivan2010 [CC BY-SA 4.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0)], from Wikimedia Commons"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Reloj_de_pendulo_Ansonia_C-1904.jpg))